# Given 10 consecutive integers, in how many ways can two of them be chosen so that their sum will be odd?

Tags: combinatorics

Not sure how to approach this problem. I tried 10/2=5, giving me the split of even and odd, then multiplied by the 10 to get 50 possible combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick the first number completely freely. So you have 10 choices. For their sum to be odd, the second number you pick must have opposite parity. There are 5 such numbers, so the total number of possible combinations appears to be $5\times 10=50$. But there are two ways of selecting each pair, so to erase this double-counting, divide by 2. This gives a final answer of $25$.

---

Another way to get to the same answer is to notice that to get a sum to be odd, one number must be even, one must be odd. So split the numbers into these two groups, and count how many ways to pair them together. That's $5\times5=25$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $5$ odds and for each one of those, you have $5$ choices of even integers to add and make the result an odd integer.

Thus you have a total of $$5\times 5 = 25$$  choices.